# combining similar records to a single record in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm working MS Access 2016, on a table that has student results: So the fields are simply studentID, Test, and Score. For reporting purposes, I need to generate a CSV file that has a student's TestScore values all in one row. So if I had:

```
StudentID:   Test:       TestScore:
A123         TestA       80
A123         TestB       90
B123         TestA       70
B123         TestB       95
```

How do I generate a table for export that looks like:

```
StudentID:   TestA:      TestB:
A123         80          90
B123         70          95
```

I don't think crosstabs would work because not all students in the table have taken all the same tests. And there are several thousand cases. I also have come to understand that may not be possible via SQL in MS Access.

Many thanks in advance for any helpful advice.

Comment: You want to have a column for every test even if no student has taken a particular test?

Comment: This is a showcase scenario for a crosstab query. Empty cells in the result are no problem.

Comment: @ June7: Yes, I'd like to have all cases (tests) included. Part of this report will be used to identify missing values (e.g., students who haven't completed a test).

Comment: @Andre I see that now! In fact if you had offered that as an answer with a brief explanation, I would have checked it.

Comment: I'm obviously not good with crosstabs, but I could figure it out to answer the stated question. Yet I notice that you can only really use a crosstab for one value? This is admittedly a different question than the OP but I'm curious: Can you use crosstab to transpose multiple values? 

What if I had a table with more information: ID, Test, Score, but also Age, Gender, X, Y, Z? I can see how I could build a series of crosstab queries, one for each value, and join them all on ID. But is there a smarter way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the ColumnHeadings property of the Crosstab Query, include all tests - "TestA";"TestB";...

Are there only a set number or could this grow?

Comment: thank you. This would be a growing number of cases. I don't think your answer will work, because the field name in the table is just "Test". If the field names were TestA, TestB, etc. I could add them as fields, but then I don't think I'd be in need of a crosstab. But if I misunderstood your answer, please clarify and I'll try it.

Comment: It works well for Months of the Year as there are only 12 so you could hard code it but if your tests are a dynamic number this method won't work

Answer (score 0):

So thank you to Andre and Alex for guiding me to this solution, which works for the original question:

Table name here is "Output".

```
TRANSFORM Last(Output.[TestScore]) AS LastOfTestScore
SELECT Output.[StudentID]
FROM [Output]
GROUP BY Output.[StudentID]
PIVOT Output.[Test];
```

For someone else searching for a similar solution, note that I used "Last" instead of something else (you might want First, Count, etc.).